# Image upload to server using html and php

Tags: php, html

I am new and experimenting with web developing.

I am attempting to upload an image to a server using the following html and php code.

```
<form action="upload_image.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">

Upload picture from source:<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Picture"> </form>



<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    if($image_name=''){
        "<script>alert('Please select a Picture to upload')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    else
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"/pictures/$image_name");
    "Your label picture has been sent";
    "/pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["$image_name"];
        "Stored in: " . "pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["$image_name"];
}
?>
```

Upon selecting a file it opens up a new web page 'upload_image.php'.

No files are being uploaded and saved to the server.

I'm sure I'm making the most basic of errors but I cannot see what it is!?

Help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're using an absolute path `/pictures` you may want to use a relative path `pictures` or `../pictures` depending on the location of your folder. Also check for folder write permissions.

Comment: To output something to the browser you need to use `echo` or `print`, simply quoting the information does nothing (eg. `echo "Your label picture has been sent.";`)

Comment: Do _not ever_ trust the “file name” send from the client – leaves you vulnerable to directory traversal attacks or other kinds of sh*t.

Comment: This code is highly dangerous. You're directly using the user-provided `['name']` parameter for the final destination of the file. This allows a malicious user to write a file anywhere on your server that they choose, and you do not check for potentially overwriting already-existing files. Plus, you simply assume that all uploads will suceeded. The `['error']` parameter in $_FILES exixsts for a reason - use it.

Comment: You also need to change `$_FILES["file"]` to `$_FILES['image']`

Comment: *Hm,* let me guess what that `*` means (grin)

Comment: Hi all.  Thanks for the info.  I certainly will look to validate and make safe the code for obvious reasons.  I have made the amendments and I am now presented with this:   when I press the upload button, the if($image_name='')is bypassed and the text is displayed with no file name.  Also when I select an image, the image name is not displayed.

Comment: please take a look at one of my previous answers about uploading files

Comment: Are you referring to anything in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely because you are using a root relative path OR the folder where you want to save it doesn't have the needed permissions. However, I am seeing that you are not validating the type of file uploaded to the server. Use the following snippet to validate file type and size:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152) //Limit file size to 2MB
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  // Code to execute if file is allowed
} else {
  // Code to execute if file is not allowed
}
```

For more info on file handling using _POST:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php